# Logic Gates: what is the relation between abstraction and number of inputs?

Tags: logic-gates

I am fairly new to this subject so please be patient.  
I am starting to study about logic gates again after 12+ years. It is ok so far except for the part of abstraction and number of inputs. 
If I am not mistaken,  the minimum number of inputs is 2. 
How does the number of inputs affect abstraction in serial processing?
How does the number of inputs affect abstraction in parallel processing?
What is the difference in the above when memory is versus is not included? 
Thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. As it stands, this reads like a homework/coursework question - is it?

Comment: @TonyM I am reading the: Elements of computing systems, at the moment. I have no trouble following along. But it seems difficult to understand that relation. So, yes I guess it is partly.

Comment: An inverter has a single input. I do not know if your book includes inverters in its definition of "logic gates".

Comment: @CL. Yes , it does. Sorry, I forgot about that one.

Comment: It appears your book uses non-standard terminology. What does "abstraction" refer to?

Comment: @CL.  It  is way too long to copy paste. And since I do not understand that relation,  I cannot describe it using my own words.

Comment: Without some context it's really a guessing game about what question we're asking.  Normally when you talk about abstraction in the context of digital logic design we mean that we're moving from a gate-by-gate description to a functional description (i.e., we're writing VHDL, Verilog or SystemC), and we're either never bothering to realize a design because it's all on paper, or we're depending on a synthesis tool to actually make the functional specification work on the target hardware.

Comment: @TimWescott  I think I need to study a little bit more so I can better explain my question. Thank you all for your time,  I will get back to this once I understood enough to do so. In the mean time,  good luck!

Comment: where are you seeing the relationship between inputs and abstraction? ... a logic symbol is an abstraction of the electronic circuit that it represents